# How to install qbittorrent from the source?

Tags: ubuntu, source-code

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I'd like to know the steps of source installation of `qbittorrent`. I know that some of you might say why bother yourself when there's `.ppa`, but I really want to learn source installation of my softwares. It's hard I know but it's the only way you get a relationship with Linux.

Comment: They actually have decent docs for building qbitorrent IIRC I did it on the raspberry pi once. I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: all this is done via console
First get the `build-essential` and `checkinstall` packages: `apt-get update` and `apt-get install build-essential checkinstall`. You will always need these: `build-essential` is a metapackage that contains basic building libraries utils needed for compiling, `checkinstall` is used to make compiled packages into `.deb`s.

Then go to wiki ([here](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Compiling-qBittorrent-on-Debian-and-Ubuntu)) and follow the instructions.

**However** after you actually compile it (running `make` with no arguments actually compiles the program) don't run `make install`, instead run `checkinstall` to build a `.deb` package that will contain all information needed to keep your compiled `qbittorrent` working and easy to remove through `dpkg` (otherwise you'd need to keep the folder with compiled qbittorrent to actually uninstall it with `make uninstall`).